# How to get audio when starting a GUI program as another user on Kubuntu 22.10 (PipeWire)?

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pipewire, multiple-users, multi-user

I currently use a command like this to start Firefox as a different user:

```sh
# using fake "get-user2-password" command abstraction here for simplicity
xhost "+SI:localuser:user2" &&
get-user2-password |
su - user2 -c "export DISPLAY=$DISPLAY ; /opt/firefox/firefox"
```

It works well, except I get no sound. I'm on Kubuntu 22.10, which uses PipeWire (it also didn't have sound before when it was PulseAudio).

How can I get sound from another user (mixing both) when I start a program (specially Firefox) on that account?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/716699/mixing-sound-from-multiple-users-processes-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make the audio working with the following:

```bash
xhost "+SI:localuser:user2" &&
pactl load-module module-native-protocol-tcp listen=127.0.0.1 &&
get-user2-password |
su - user2 -w DISPLAY -c "export PULSE_SERVER=tcp:127.0.0.1:4713 ; /opt/firefox/firefox"
```

assuming you have installed `pipewire-pulse` and `pulseaudio-utils` packages.